# Primefaces TabView iFrame Height

Tags: css, iframe, primefaces

I have a problem. For my website I use Primefaces. I have 4 Sites and one index.xhtml. On the index should be an TabView. In each Tab I have an iFrame, to include the 4 sites.

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="jmsstatus">
    <p:tabView dynamic="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <p:tab title="Site0">
            <iframe src="site0.xhtml" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"/>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Site1">
            <iframe src="site1.xhtml" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"/>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Site2">
            <iframe src="site2.xhtml" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"/>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Site3">
            <iframe src="site3.xhtml" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

My Problem is, that each tab only has a height of maybe 20%, so theres a Scrollpane on the side, and you see only a litte part of the iframe. I want, that each tab has a height of 100%.

How can I do that? I can't find an answer.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have found an answer on my own. You have to use <p:tabMenu and   <p:menuitem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use this script to set height in iframes,

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
   obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

in iframe use this code segment to call function,

```
<iframe src="" width="100%" style="border-width: 0PX;" scrolling="no" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'/>
```